# How to create a loosely-coupled aggregator function in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, algorithm, data-structures

In my application, I have a function for aggregating numeric stats from a database using a Map and iterating over each object in the data array. Currently, my solution is extremely tightly coupled with every property explicitly stated within the function:

```
const aggregateStats = (dataframe: IBasicOffensePlayerStats[]) => {
    let teamsMap = new Map();

    for (let obj in dataframe) {
        if (teamsMap.get(dataframe[obj].player_id)) {
            let currentObj = teamsMap.get(dataframe[obj].player_id);
            let newObj = {
                player_id: dataframe[obj].player_id,
                week_count:
                    Number.parseInt(currentObj.week_count.toString()) +
                    Number.parseInt(dataframe[obj].week_count.toString()),
                pass_attempt:
                    Number.parseInt(currentObj.pass_attempt.toString()) +
                    Number.parseInt(dataframe[obj].pass_attempt.toString()),
                completion:
                    Number.parseInt(currentObj.completion.toString()) +
                    Number.parseInt(dataframe[obj].completion.toString()),
                incompletion:
                    Number.parseInt(currentObj.incompletion.toString()) +
                    Number.parseInt(dataframe[obj].incompletion.toString()),
                game_id_db: currentObj.game_id_db,
                team_abbr: currentObj.team_abbr,
                position: currentObj.position,
            };
            teamsMap.set(currentObj.player_id, newObj);
        } else {
            teamsMap.set(dataframe[obj].player_id, {
                ...dataframe[obj],
            });
        }
    }
    return Array.from(teamsMap.values());
};
```

In the function, the "dataframe" parameter is an array of an interface I have defined:

```
export interface IBasicOffensePlayerStats {
    player_id: string;
    position: string;
    game_id_db: string;
    pass_attempt: number;
    completion: number;
    incompletion: number;
    week_count: number;
}
```

In essence, the function populates a map by looping through each "IBasicOffensePlayerStats" object and checking for if the identifier (in this case, `player_id`) is present. If it is present, each of the numeric values (week_count, pass_attempt, completion, and incompletion) is aggregated (added), and the string values are just saved as the last occurring value.

The data looks something like the following:

```
const playerData: IBasicOffensePlayerStats[] = [{player_id: "L.Jackson", position: "QB", game_id_db: "2022_01_BAL_NYJ, pass_attempt: 28, completion: 18, incompletion: 10, week_count: 1}, {player_id: "L.Jackson", position: "QB", game_id_db: "2022_02_BAL_MIA, pass_attempt: 31, completion: 20, incompletion: 11, week_count: 1}, {player_id: "J.Burrow", position: "QB", game_id_db: "2022_03_NYJ_CIN, pass_attempt: 43, completion: 28, incompletion: 15, week_count: 1}]
```

As you can see, there are two objects with "L.Jackson" as the value for the `player_id` property. In this instance, the function would return:

```
[{player_id: "L.Jackson", position: "QB", game_id_db: "2022_02_BAL_MIA, pass_attempt: 59, completion: 38, incompletion: 21, week_count: 2}, {player_id: "J.Burrow", position: "QB", game_id_db: "2022_03_NYJ_CIN, pass_attempt: 43, completion: 28, incompletion: 15, week_count: 1}]
```

Because it would aggregate (add) the numeric properties for "L.Jackson" across both objects, and "J.Burrow" would be unchanged because there was only one instance of an object with that `player_id`.

Is there a way that I can loosely couple this function where if I add a `passing_yards` property or include a new string value, I do not need to rewrite the function?

Comment: Could you [edit] the data so that it's a [mre]? Right now it's syntactically invalid and missing a property so that you get a runtime error if you use it.  If you make it easy for others to play around with the code you increase the chance of getting a useful answer.

Comment: My suggestion looks something like [this](//tsplay.dev/NB5Kbw), where the part that addresses your question looks like "pass a list of keys to aggregate to your function (or keep the list somewhere static like [this](//tsplay.dev/mbQpbN)) and iterate over it", and the rest of it is refactoring to be cleaner (stop iterating over arrays using `in`; don't convert numbers-to-strings-to-numbers, give types to the map entries, etc).  Does this meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing? (Pls mention @jcalz to notify me if you reply)

Comment: @jcalz hey, I apologize for the confusion in my question. I believe I edited the data to be reproducible; let me know if there is any more clarification you'd like. And it looks like your solution is perfect; thank you! I am unfamiliar with the Record data type, but it seems fairly intuitive. You're phenomenal!

Comment: You should probably check your data in an IDE to get it to be reproducible. I still see unterminated string literals in there, so I know it's not valid. I'm happy to write up an answer but it would be nice if I didn't have to debug the question. Also, could you tell me [which of these solutions](https://tsplay.dev/Wy6Lgw) is more applicable? That is, will you be adding new properties statically (every call to `aggregateStats()` aggregates the same stats, but these keys might change over time in your code base) or dynamically (each call might be given an array with different keys)?

Answer (score 0):

A fairly simple approach in plain JS is to alter a typical `groupBy` function to handle fields whose value is numeric, adding those and carrying the others directly through.  It might look like this:

```js
const group = (xs) => Object .values ( 
  xs .reduce ((a, x) => {
    a [x .player_id] = x .player_id in a
      ? Object .fromEntries (Object .entries (x) .map (
          ([k, v]) => [k, typeof v == "number" ? (a [x .player_id] [k] || 0) + v: v]
        ))
      : x
    return a
  }, {})
)

const playerData = [{player_id: "L.Jackson", position: "QB", game_id_db: "2022_01_BAL_NYJ", pass_attempt: 28, completion: 18, incompletion: 10, week_count: 1}, {player_id: "L.Jackson", position: "QB", game_id_db: "2022_02_BAL_MIA", pass_attempt: 31, completion: 20, incompletion: 11, week_count: 1}, {player_id: "J.Burrow", position: "QB", game_id_db: "2022_03_NYJ_CIN", pass_attempt: 43, completion: 28, incompletion: 15, week_count: 1}]

console .log (group (playerData))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

That is simple enough, and may be all you need.  But if you want more control, deciding to total some fields, choose the maximum from another, list all the values of a third, and just carry a fourth one through, we probably want something more generic.  We could do this by passing in a configuration object which determines how to start a field and how to combine the current one with the previous ones.

Here's one approach:

```js
const group = (config) => {
  const handlers = Object .fromEntries (Object .values (config .transforms) .flatMap (
    ({fields, init, transform}) => fields .map (f => [f, {init, transform}])
  ))

  return (xs) => Object .values ( 
    xs .reduce ((a, x) => {
      const key = config .keys .map (k => x [k] || '') .join ('\u0000')
      a [key] = Object .fromEntries (Object .entries (x) .map (
        ([k, v, {transform, init} = handlers [k] || config .defaultTransform]) => 
          [k, k in (a [key] || {}) ? transform (a [key] [k], v) : init (v)]
      ))
      return a
    }, {})
  )
}

const groupPlayers = group ({
  keys: ['player_id'],
  transforms: {
    total: {
      fields: ['pass_attempt', 'completion', 'incompletion', 'week_count'], 
      init: (a) => a, 
      transform: (a, b) => a + b
    },
    list: {
      fields: ['game_id_db'], 
      init: (a) => [a], 
      transform: (a, b) => a .concat (b)
    }
  },
  defaultTransform: {
    init: (a) => a, 
    transform: (a, b) => a
  }
})


const playerData = [{player_id: "L.Jackson", position: "QB", game_id_db: "2022_01_BAL_NYJ", pass_attempt: 28, completion: 18, incompletion: 10, week_count: 1}, {player_id: "L.Jackson", position: "QB", game_id_db: "2022_02_BAL_MIA", pass_attempt: 31, completion: 20, incompletion: 11, week_count: 1}, {player_id: "J.Burrow", position: "QB", game_id_db: "2022_03_NYJ_CIN", pass_attempt: 43, completion: 28, incompletion: 15, week_count: 1}]

console .log (groupPlayers (playerData))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

And we can imagine many variants of this, perhaps a `Transforms` module that we used to configure like this:

```js
const groupPlayers = group ({
  __default__: Transforms .noop,
  completion: Transforms .total,
  game_id_db: Transforms .list, 
  incompletion: Transforms .total,
  pass_attempt: Transforms .total,
  week_count: Transforms .total,
})
```

It should be relatively trivial to code that one.

In any case, the code above is all in JS.  I don't know (and don't particularly care) how to transform it to idiomatic TS.  I'm afraid the generic cases might be difficult, but I'm not sure.